# Is there a shortcut to CLOSE Chrome's developer tool?

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

I know about `F12` and `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `C` shortcuts but I can't find anywhere a shortcut to *close* the developer tools window on Chrome. Is there one?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**DOCKED Developer tools!**

> **Open/close developer tool (re-open last tab (start with 'Elements'):**
>
> - WIN: **`CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `I`**
> - MAC OS: **`CMD` + `ALT` + `I`**

> **Open/close developer tool (console tab)**
>
> - WIN: **`CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `J`**
> - MAC OS: **`CMD` + `SHIFT` + `J`**

> **`F12`** = open/close developer tool (re-open last tab (start with 'Elements')

**UNDOCKED Developer tools ->**
Same as above but the first two create multiple tabs where F12 should close the tab :)

> If you need any other shortcut of chrome please try the website given below, but I am not sure if everything is on it... The `CTRL + SHIFT + I` is not even on it (when writing this)...
>
> > **Website:** 'https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en'

Comment: If the devtools is undocked, then ctrl-shift-I will instead inspect the devtools.

Comment: This no longer works. F12 now just switches back to your main window instead of closing the dev tools.

Answer (score 8):

If the DevTools window is **docked**, <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> will close the window.

If the DevTools window is **undocked** in a separate window, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> will close it **if** it is the active window.

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to toggle between a docked and undocked DevTools window.

So if the window is undocked, you can quickly press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>,<kbd>I</kbd> to close it.

[More shortcuts here.](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts)

Comment: _Thank you._ `Ctrl+Shift+D`,`F12` works for me to close a focused undocked devtools window. I cannot express what a relief it is to have shortcut that works.

Answer (score 7):

For Mac OS it's `cmd + alt(option) + j`. This will toggle the developer tool. One can also use `cmd + shift + c` for inspect element.

Answer (score 4):

#### MAC OS:

`Cmd + Alt(option) + i`

- works to open/hide an inspector

---

*ps please check [accepted question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42906082/1698467). I updated it with full detils.*

Answer (score 2):

The Developer Tools keyboard shortcuts for Mac and Others are now listed [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts).

It includes the much-needed

> Close the active tab: Alt+W

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is looking for how to close the [image: console drawer] (I didn't know it was a "drawer"), when you're looking at some other Dev Tools tab (e.g. Elements), you simply want to hit `⎋` a.k.a. the `Escape` key ‍♂️.

This works [for both Windows and Mac](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/shortcuts/#global).